# Timestamp display in macOS Finder

Tags: finder

I noticed some very odd behaviour in macOS High Sierra's (10.13.1) Finder.

For filenames that contain timestamps Finder changes the timestamp format, the two screenshots below illustrate the issue. [image: actual filename in terminal]

[image: filename as displayed in Finder]

Any idea how to stop Finder from changing the time stamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**
That's because the file you created through the terminal using the `touch` command was named that way by you (not the system) upon creation. What happens is that upon creation, the system interprets your chosen filename and checks whether it contains any "illegal characters".

In macOS, the only "illegal" filename character is colon symbol (`:`). This is because macOS use these in path names e.g. `Macintosh HD:Applications:Safari.app`. Additionally, file and folder names may be up to 255 characters in length.

The replacement of `:` into `/` is an automatic function built-in to macOS to prevent file path corruption through inadvertently placing a colon in the middle of a file name - which would change the entire path. **You will not be able to adjust this behavior.**

**What about Screenshots?**
As for the screenshots, their file names do not contain any so-called "illegal;" characters and are hence valid.

**Additionally,** changing the screenshot file name is also very easy in macOS. In Terminal, run `defaults write com.apple.screencapture name "Some Name"` - replacing `Some Name` with your own text.